# How to set sassOptions in Vite

Tags: sass, vite

With webpack, we can set sassOptions like below:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
  options: {
    sassOptions: { quietDeps: true },
  },
}
```

Following the [vite document](https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-preprocessoroptions), I'm trying to config as below:

```
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        sassOptions: { quietDeps: true },
      },
    },
  },
```

But it seems not work for me. What I need is to hide third-party sass deps's warning message in terminal.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I got `ReferenceErrror: scss is not defined` here.

Comment: None till now. I've also asked on GitHub, but not response...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To hide the warnings, update your `vite.config.js` like this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        quietDeps: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is working for me with vite 3.1.8 and sass 1.55.0.  Can anyone else confirm it working? I am trying to suppress warnings about `/` in font-awesome 4... it's possible this arg just doesn't work to do that, although it's suggested elsewhere it ought to.

Answer (score 5):

The [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions) want you to put the settings in `css.preprocessorOptions.scss.quiet`, as others have mentioned. This however does not work, and it isn't Vite's fault, it's Sass's.

The problem is that the Sass devs have made 3 very dumb decisions:

1. They [don't want](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/2587#issuecomment-459523943) anyone to ever be able to turn off deprecation warnings, because as soon as those features are removed from the language and go from warnings to errors, they will be [flooded with GitHub issues](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2822#issuecomment-482914373).
2. They made one exception, which is if a dependency is the cause, then you can "quiet" *just those*.
3. But then they made it so that their [definition of a "dependency" is](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/StringOptionsWithoutImporter#quietDeps) so strict that it is unlikely anyone actually meets that criteria, so you can't actually turn off the deprecation warnings (their intended outcome).

**Your options:**

1. Create Issues or PR's to fix the warnings in the dependencies you use.

   - Cool in theory, but what if they're already fixed, and you are just looking to avoid upgrading your entire component library dependency because the project isn't worth that effort.
2. You can use `sass` version `1.32.13`, the last version without the warnings (worked for me, though this feels like a shitty solution)
3. Try to adjust your code to work with the rigid system they define as a "dependency" (good luck)
4. Drop Sass all-together and use something else (the new Sass API kinda sucks anyways)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead:

```js
css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                quietDeps: true,
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.